# XFS for a beginner

Tags: 22.04, xfs

I'm using UBU 22.04 LTS and need to partition a USB stick with xfs file system.DISKS app says i don't have mkfs.xfs or something like that.How do i solve this?Complete novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mkfs.xfs is provided by xfsprogs in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfsprogs
```

Comment: Mission accomplished,thank you Karel!